# Centralized Error Handling for Firestore API Methods in Next.js Admin Dashboard (Error not natively Handled)

Tags: error-handling

I'm building an admin dashboard app using Firestore, TypeScript, and Next.js and want to implement centralized error handling at the data level for its API methods. I plan to have a separate error handling mecanism on each level of the App.

Question:

**Can I simply:**

Extend the built-in Error class?
Export specific error classes directly to the API methods file?
Is the potential coupling risk significant at the data layer?
Alternative:

**Or Should I avoid the Error class entirely?**
Create a custom abstract error class with methods?
Inject it into the API methods?

**Best Practices:**

Are there any recommended approaches beyond those listed above?

**Can I simply:**

Extend the built-in Error class?
Export specific error classes directly to the API methods file?
Is the potential coupling risk significant at the data layer?
Alternative:

**Or Should I avoid the Error class entirely?**
Create a custom abstract error class with methods?
Inject it into the API methods?

**Best Practices:**

Are there any recommended approaches beyond those listed above?